# How can i call javascript from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I wanna use jQuery Price Range Slider With Products Interface on the website, i find some examples but they added php, how can call with c# this javascript?

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.8rc1.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8rc1.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            $slider = $("#slider");//Caching slider object

            $amount = $("#amount");//Caching amount object

            $slider.slider({

                range: true, // necessary for creating a range slider

                min: 0, // minimum range of slider

                max: 500, //maximimum range of slider

                values: [75, 300], //initial range of slider

                slide: function(event, ui) { // This event is triggered on every mouse move during slide.

                    $amount.html('$' + ui.values[0] + ' - $' + ui.values[1]);//set value of  amount span to current slider values

                }

            });



            $amount.html('$' + $slider.slider("values", 0) + ' - $' + $slider.slider("values", 1));

        });

    </script>

    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">

        body{font-size: 12px;font-family:"Arial","Helvetica","Verdana","sans-serif";}

        .left{float:left;}

        .clear{clear:both}

        #wrapper{margin:40px auto;width:940px}

        #leftSlider{width: 200px;margin-right: 30px;}

        #range{margin-bottom: 20px;}

        #products{width:710px}

        #products ul{

            list-style: none;

            margin:0px;padding:0px

        }

        #products ul li{

            margin:4px;

            float:left;

            height:180px;

            width:200px;

            background-color: #333;

            -moz-border-radius:6px;

            -webkit-border-radius:6px;

            -khtml-border-radius:6px;

        }

        #amount{font-size: 14px; text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ccc}

    </style>

</head>



<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class="left" id="leftSlider">

            <div id="range">Price Range <span id="amount"></span></div>

            <div id="slider"></div>

        </div>

        <div class="left" id="products">

            <ul>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

                <li></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>



 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You haven't any PHP code there. So, how can we suggest what must be your C# code if your code isn't server-side?

Comment: one reason not to depend on examples is that, as in this case, seeing an example doesn't necessarily help you to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

From [**MSDN docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)

```
public static void RegisterStartupScript(
    Control control,
    Type type,
    string key,
    string script,
    bool addScriptTags
)
```

#### Parameters

> **control**
>       Type: System.Web.UI.Control
>       The control that is registering the client script block.
>
> **type**
>       Type: System.Type
>       The type of the client script block. This parameter is usually
>   specified by using the typeof operator
>   (C#) or the GetType operator (Visual
>   Basic) to retrieve the type of the
>   control that is registering the
>   script.
>
> **key**
>       Type: System.String
>       A unique identifier for the script block.
>
> **script**
>       Type: System.String
>       The script.
>
> **addScriptTags**
>       Type: System.Boolean
>       true to enclose the script block with  and  tags;
>   otherwise, false.

This will generate a script block on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you don't have any php code in the page. You can embed this code to page and can call function

```
 
$(function('name') {
});
```

by giving  a name to this function from code behind using [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) method.

Hope this will help.